# Flex: application is confused when passing variables to custom component

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript, flex4

I'm new to Flex and I'm missing something very basic about architecting a Flex application -- I've implemented a custom component `MyReportGrid` and extended `GridColumn` with `MyColumn`. I've tried to outline the application code below.

The interesting thing to notice is that class `OfficeItems` is used by class `MyItems`, and the `MyColumn` (which extends `GridColumn`) includes a `customPath` variable that is used to access variables `pen`, `pencil`, and `stapler` inside class `OfficeItems`.

I believe that is the reason why manually sorting (by clicking on the columns in the datagrid) only works for columns corresponding to `zipCode` and `stateCode` and NOT `pen`, `pencil`, and `stapler`.

Also, when I try to use a simple labelFunction for `zipCode` or `stateCode` it always works fine, but implementing a labelFunction for `pen`, `pencil`, or `stapler` never works. By "never works" I mean that the labelFunction is called correctly, and it performs it's required task in that the labelFunction receives the correct object and actually returns the correct formatted String, but this returned value is never displayed in the datagrid (I'm assuming the `customPath` variable confuses the labelFunction as to which variable the returned String maps to).

I think these are both the same issue in that the `customPath` aspect of the `MyColumn` confuses the application. Any idea how to fix the sorting and/or labelFunction? Thanks in advance for your patience in reading this (long) posting.

The classes are:

```
package com.supportClasses  
{
    public class OfficeItems {
    public var pen:*;
    public var pencil:*;
    public var stapler:*;
    }
}
```

and

```
package com.models
{
    import com.supportClasses.OfficeItems;
    [Bindable]
    public class MyItems extends Model {
        public function myItems() {
            super();
        }
        public var office:OfficeItems;
        public var zipCode:int;
        public var stateCode:String;
    }
}
```

The data grid looks like:

```
...
<components:MyReportGrid id="myGrid" dataProvider="{_myData}"...>
    <components:columns>
        <fx:Array>
            <supportClasses:MyColumn customPath="office" dataField="pen"... />
            <supportClasses:MyColumn customPath="office" dataField="pencil"... />
            <supportClasses:MyColumn customPath="office" dataField="stapler"... />
            <supportClasses:MyColumn dataField="zipCode"... />
            <supportClasses:MyColumn dataField="stateCode"... />
            ...
```

where `_myData` has a class of `MyItems` (note: the `customPath` feature is ignored by `MyColumn` when not present here, such as for `zipCode` and `stateCode`). `MyColumn` is:

```
package com.components.supportClasses {
    import spark.components.gridClasses.GridColumn;
    public class MyColumn extends GridColumn
    {
        public var customPath:String="";
        ...
        public function MyColumn(headerText:String="header" customPath:String="", dataField:String="data", ...) {
           this.headerText=headerText;
           this.customPath=customPath;
           this.dataField=dataField;
           ...
        }
    }
}
```

and MyReportGrid is:

```
package com.models {
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <s:Group xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"    
         xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
         xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
         width="400" height="300">
       import com.components.myClasses.MyColumn;
       import com.itemRenderers.myItemRenderer;
       import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;
       import mx.collections.ArrayList;
       import mx.collections.ListCollectionView;
       import spark.components.gridClasses.GridColumn;
       ...
       <s:DataGrid width="100%" ... />
    </s:Group>
}
```

the labelFunction is:

```
private function redFormat(item:Object, column:MyColumn):String {
   var formatResult:String = "red "+item.office.pen;
   return formatResult; // returns "red Bic15938" (for example)
}
```

as called from:

```
<supportClasses:MyColumn customPath="office" dataField="pen" labelFunction="redFormat"... />
```

Comment: Is there a particular reason you extend from `GridColumn`? You shouldn't do this unless you want to alter or add to its functionality. I have never needed to do so. What is the goal of this `customPath`?

Comment: Extend is used to make `GridColumn` dynamic. The goal of `customPath` is related to how the models used by the application work together. For example, class `OfficeItems` maps to a middle-tier model, whereas `MyItems` is a client-side model.

Comment: You should work with a proxy model class then instead of using a custom view class just to tie your model together.

Comment: Without major surgery, is there some way to help the application access the functions it expects to find when working with the usual `GridColumn`?

Comment: I guess so, but I have too little information to provide a concrete answer to that. In general terms (and if I understand your situation correctly) you keep your two model classes intact and wrap them in a new 'proxy' class that exposes the properties needed by the DataGrid and feed a collection of these proxies to the DG. You could also consider using [ObjectProxy](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/utils/ObjectProxy.html) to do this job.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a guess, but could it be something like adding a "toString" function to the OfficeItems class? (I would be using comments, but still working on getting reputation.)