# Function binding not set after model is injected

Tags: apache-flex, datagrid, parsley, datagridcolumn

I have a CustomDataGrid that extends from DataGrid and CustomDataGridColumn that extends from DataGridColumn.

CustomDataGridColumn has member variables of type Function.

Inside my view, I inject a presentation model using parsley.

The code is as follows:

```
<fx:Declarations> 
        <spicefactory:Configure/> 
    </fx:Declarations> 

<fx:Script> 

        [Inject(id="associatedDocumentsPM")] 
        [Bindable] 
        public var model:AssociatedDocumentsPM; 


</fx:Script> 

   <customDataGrid:CustomDataGrid id="AssocDocGrid" 
                                   width="100%" height="{(documentDataList.length+2)*20}" 
                                   doubleClickEnabled="true" enabled="{modeHandler.appEnable}" 
                                   dataP="{documentDataList}" 
                                   sortableColumns="false"> 
        <customDataGrid:columnList> 
            <customDataGrid:CustomDataGridColumn 
                textAlign="left" 
                dataFieldIdentifier="documentName" 
                headerText="Document Type" 
                modifyLabelField="{model.modifyLabelField}" 
                dataField="documentName" 
                isNaNZero="true" 
                showDataTips="true" 
                editable="false"/> 
                ...more columns here...  
       </customDataGrid:columnList>
    </customDataGrid:CustomDataGrid>
```

The AssociatedDocumentsPM has functions defined and these are set in the columns.

One example being for attribute `modifyLabelField="{model.modifyLabelField}"`

CustomDataGridColumn.myLabelField is of type Function. myLabelField inside AssociatedDocumentsPM is a public function.

The Parsley Context file is in the parent of the above file and declares the PM as follows:

AssocDocPMFactory is a class with a sole function decorated with [Factory].

So the problem is the following:

When I debug the application and check the columnList of the DataGrid, the variable modifyLabelField is null.

Are function bindings treated differently than variables? I'm using Flex 4.5.1 together with Parsley 2.4.1

I understand that injection could happen after creationComplete is invoked but I thought the binding would take care of that.

I have a feeling that the model - the PM - is null until much much later and the function binding is not triggered.

I tried to use FastInject as well but to no avail.

Is this a problem with function pointers and Flex binding?

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but an observation: you shouldn't extend GridColumn unless you want to alter or add to its functionality. There hardly ever is any need for that. I recently had a [similar discussion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10520158/flex-application-is-confused-when-passing-variables-to-custom-component).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it isn't. If you have these kind of doubts, it's always a good idea to quickly set up a simple isolated test situation that verifies your assumption. I created the following to test yours:

```
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               creationComplete="onCreationComplete()" >

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            private function onCreationComplete():void {
                test = function(item:*):String {
                    return "AAA";
                }
            }

            [Bindable]
            private var test:Function;
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <s:List labelFunction="{test}">
        <s:dataProvider>
            <s:ArrayList>
                <fx:String>A</fx:String>
                <fx:String>B</fx:String>
                <fx:String>C</fx:String>
            </s:ArrayList>
        </s:dataProvider>
    </s:List>

</s:Application>
```

If the `test` Function variable is declared `Bindable`, you'll see 3 times "AAA". If you remove the `Bindable` metadata, you'll see "A", "B", "C".

So clearly binding works with function pointers too (and you'll have to look elsewhere to find your nullpointer).